# Hide price for specific category if user role not logged in

Tags: woocommerce

I need to hide product price for a category, but show it once user logged in.
The following code hides price for those not logged in. How can I apply this to a specific product category only?

```
add_action( 'init', 'hide_price_add_cart_not_logged_in' );
  
function hide_price_add_cart_not_logged_in() {   
   if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {      
      remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
      remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
      remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );
      remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10 );   
      add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'print_login_to_see', 31 );
      add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'print_login_to_see', 11 );
   }
}
  
function print_login_to_see() {
   echo '<a href="' . get_permalink(wc_get_page_id('myaccount')) . '">' . __('Login to see prices', 'theme_name') . '</a>';
}
```

Comment: You can add this code in child theme's functions.php file

Comment: Sorry, which code are you referring to? I've already added the above to functions.php, but need to add a product category filter to it.